# Azure Redis cache premium deployment failure

Tags: azure, deployment, redis

I'm deploying a P1 Redis cache in Azure, using the new portal. There's not much to the deployment, and everything checks out as valid and it lets me start the creation process. I'm adding the Redis to a VNET, and an empty subnet within that VNET, as I'll need a static IP.

After about an hour of "creating", it fails. It just lists the status as "Failed", and the console is not available. I can't find any details about the failure.

I've rolled out plenty of Redis caches that were Basic and Standard tier with no problems. Any idea why this one might be failing?

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem here was actually the result of the section on the following page titled:

**What are some common misconfiguration issues with Azure Redis Cache and VNets?**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-how-to-premium-vnet

The fairly large table of required network settings has to all be exactly right. Mine was too locked down (and opening up this many things has kind of defeated the purpose my organization was after in adding the Redis to a VNET, but that's a whole other topic.)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. The correct hint is on the page you linked in your answer, but I will outline it here directly for others: "When you deploy Azure Cache for Redis to a Resource Manager virtual network, the cache must be in a dedicated subnet that contains no other resources except for Azure Cache for Redis instances. If you attempt to deploy an Azure Cache for Redis instance to a Resource Manager virtual network subnet that contains other resources, the deployment fails."

I tried it with a subnet where other resources where in. This does not work. Hope that helps.